# How to use as little for loop as possible to get results

Tags: python

I have two inputs: `proof_paths` and `augment_number` as follows.

**Inputs**

```
augment_number = 2    
proof_paths = [[('#1', 'nationality'), ('#2', 'placeOfBirth'), ('#3', 'locatedIn')],
               [('#1', 'nationality'), ('#2', 'hasFather'), ('#3', 'nationality')]]
```

I'm going to take words from proof_paths except #1, #2, and #3, create a single list, and copy as many as the augment number throughout proof_paths. My desired output is as follows.

**output**

```
[[['nationality', 'placeOfBirth', 'locatedIn'],
  ['nationality', 'placeOfBirth', 'locatedIn']],
  
 [['nationality', 'hasFather', 'nationality'],
  ['nationality', 'hasFather', 'nationality']]]
```

I want to know the code that allows me to get the output I want by using as little as possible for loop.

**Edits**

I tried as below to get the above results.
I wonder if there is a way to get the result without for loop.

```
[[list(map(lambda x : x[1], path))]*augment_number for path in proof_paths]
```

Comment: did you try to use another `map` instead of  `for`-loop? `map( ..., proof_paths)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `map()` instead of `for`-loop.

You have list comprehension

```
 [ ... for path in proof_paths]
```

which you can write as

```
 map(lambda path: .... , proof_paths)
```

And it gives

```
 list(map(lambda path:[list(map(lambda x : x[1], path))]*augment_number, proof_paths))
```

which works without `for`-loops (but `map` is hidden loop) but it is unreadable for human.